# How do I compile/run C++ code in the console?

Tags: compiling, gcc, c++, console, g++

I'm trying to run my C++ code using the console. I used the header file `conio.h` like I did when I used Turbo C++ IDE in Windows, and I ran the code in console using

```
g++ filename.cpp
```

I have installed [build-essentials [image: Install build-essentials]](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/build-essentials) previously, but still I get the message:

> ```
> conio.h file : No such file or directory
> ```

I have poked around a bit and learned that the header files for Windows and Linux differs, but am still to find a way to get all the header files required for basic and intermediate coding practice.

Help on this is appreciated. Please keep in mind that I'm very new to Ubuntu.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`conio.h` is a library that is windows specific. To my knowledge it comes with `mingw32`, a compiler that is a windows port of `gcc`. Try to set up your code so that it doesn't use it.

Also, note that linux uses (99% of the time) the [gnu standard library (gnulibc)](http://www.gnu.org/software/libc/). You can find its content [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C_standard_library)

---

For input/output you'd need the `iostream` (not `iostream.h`) header file. You can look at a more elaborate and complete list [here](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/header).

Comment: So could you please make clear what are the basic header files that are required to run a cpp program (basic I/O and so forth) ? And is ncurses package really required as I read elsewhere?

Comment: updated the answer.

Comment: Afaik conio.h is not included in minGW, It is difficult to implement conio.h functions using iostream, so you should use ncurses or similar libraries for this purpose

Comment: thank you @green7 , the link is quite comprehensive and was one of the things I was looking for.
Could you please tell me which package I need to install for the standard library header files to be available? Or is it already in the build-essentials package that I have installed?

Comment: You don't need to install anything. Just write the program and compile it using `g++`

Answer (score 1):

conio.h is turbo c++ specific header file, it is not a standard c++ header file

usage `#include<headerfile.h>` is no longer supported in c++, It is replaced by `#include<headerfile>`

Eg: use `#include<iostream>` instead of `#include<iostream.h>`

You can run turbo c++ in linux using dosbox, But it is highly discouraged, Always use standard syntax while learning a programming language

Comment: #include instead of #include? please review your comment.
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The `<iostream.h>` header is old and deprecated.  Instead you should use `<iostream>` which is the new header. If you still get an error about your header file then check your include directories. Go to "Option" > "Directories..." and check your "Include Directories" for example: `/home/user/cpp/custom-includes/`